# What are the best alternatives to sentence structure "A, but B; therefore C?"

Tags: writing-style

I'm stuck in a rut. Today I wrote, "I planned to reboot my computer once a week, but an update forced it, so I left it up the rest of that week."

I feel like I use that structure too much, but that's how my mind works. I think logically. What are the best alternatives for communicating this logical sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invert the sentence. "I did not reboot my computer this week. I had planned to, but an update forced it earlier." Or even "I did not reboot my computer this week because an update forced it to reboot earlier."

Those both sound clearer to me, actually, since they place the subject and predicate first, establishing context before giving an explanation.

Comment: It's been 2 months. I should mark this accepted. Thank you for your help!